# fetching multiple MySQL rows based on a specific input within one of the table columns

Tags: php, mysql, rows

I am trying to fetch all rows within a MySQL table that have a specific input within a particular column.
Here is my table:

```
ID  COLOR   LENGTH 
--- ------- ------
19  red     10 
3   green   45 
24  blue    54 
4   red     3 
5   red     11
```

How would I fetch all the the rows that have `"red"` as the stored value within the `"COLOR"` column? Can somebody please help?

I am a newbie to MySQL/PHP, so forgive me if this is a stupid question. I tried looking all over but I could not find an answer to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're a newbie, I'd like to recommend proper SQL coding. Name all the columns you need, even if you need all the columns that exist in your table. Avoid using the `SELECT * ...` approach. Develop good practices and habits as early as today:

```
SELECT ID, COLOR, LENGTH FROM table WHERE COLOR = 'red';
```

A very basic example of how you'd get things done in PHP:

```php
<?php
# variables you will need. values below are mere examples only
$server = 'localhost';
$database = 'databasename';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

# create database connection
try {
    $pdodb = new PDO('mysql:host='.$server.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
    $pdodb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    printf($ex->getMessage());
    exit;
}

# use prepared statements, for starters:
$stmt = $pdodb->prepare("SELECT ID, COLOR, LENGTH FROM table WHERE COLOR = ?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, 'red')
$stmt->execute();

# store each row into an array
$resultset = array();
do {
    $resultset[] = $onerow; 
} while ($onerow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN));

# to test your resultset:
print_r($resultset); # use this only to display during debugging/testing
?>
```

Here are links to articles that can help you get started:

[net.tutsplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

[phpeveryday](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Data-Object/PDO-Tutorial-P842.html)

[phpro](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for this very comprehensive response. I will ensure to you apply these tips in my coding. I also have an additional question if you don't mind... How long would it take to apply the process above to extract hundreds of rows out of thousands? what about hundreds of thousands? Is MySQL the right database for that kind of work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wolfgang, it would be good to first re-evaluate (in case the table has been set up already) the data structure of your tables and/database model.. There is a thing called `index` that aids in the performance of search (`SELECT...`) queries and the like.. First, you can go read here to get a basic grasp of data modeling, which will let you gain an ability (if not basic) to understand how to structure your data. [Data Modeling 101](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/dataModeling101.html) .. As for determining the amount of time required to complete a certain query, it is something that depends on

Comment: what you ultimately need to accomplish, the amount of rows you have, the indexes/constraints in place, the hardware your database and application is hosted in.. etc.. You can also perform a search here in stackoverflow.. I guarantee you.. you'll find a ton load of interesting things, and you'll learn a lot..

Comment: I really appreciate your help Nonym. This is very useful information. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

See `mysql_fetch_assoc` (ref.: http://de.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc). The very first example gives you every information you need.

The sql needs to be replaced by:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE color = 'red'
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a casual `where` condition:

```
select * from thetable where color = 'red';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `WHERE` clause on your query ([documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html)).

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE color = 'red'; // red ones
SELECT * FROM table WHERE color != 'red'; // all but the red ones
SELECT * FROM table WHERE color = 'red' OR color = 'blue'; // red and blue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a query as following

```
$query="select * from <table_name> where <column_name>=<your_input>";
```

Now run they query using

```
$result="mysql_query($query)";
```

Atlast write a code to fetch all your data

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   //do your operations here i'll store it in array
   $arr[]= array("<colum-name"=>$row['<column-name'],....);
}
```